# Asp.net Core Linq query takes too much time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have a linq query which is takes 31 second. This is the first time that im getting that much late query and i dont know what to do.
Let me show you to my query :

```
        public IEnumerable<WebFairField> WebFairFieldForFair(Guid ID)
        {
            return TradeTurkDBContext.WebFairField.Where(x => x.DataGuidID==ID)
             .Include(x => x.Category)
             //
             .Include(x=>x.FairSponsors)
             .ThenInclude(x=>x.Company)
             .ThenInclude(x=>x.FileRepos)
             //
             .Include(x=>x.WebFairHalls)
             .ThenInclude(x=>x.HallSeatingOrders)
             .ThenInclude(x=>x.Company)
             .ThenInclude(x=>x.FileRepos)
             //
             .Include(x=>x.HallExpertComments)
             .Include(x=>x.Products)
             .Include(x=>x.FairSponsors)
             .AsNoTracking().ToList();
        }
```

im sure about that this is a right query but i dont know why that query is tooking too much time.

**Thanks for any help!!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called Cartesian Explosion. EF Core produces SQL which returns a lot of records which will be aggregated on the client side.

Schematically: `FairSponsors * FairSponsor.Company.FileRepos * WebFairHalls * WebFairHall.HallSeatingOrders * WebFairHall.HallSeatingOrder.Company.FileRepos * HallExpertComments * Poducts * FairSponsors`. Too much records, isn't?

EF Core has operator `AsSplitQuery()`. Try to apply to your query and probably it will speedup returning result, but not too much. Each collection requested in `Include` will produce additional query.

Also try to play with removing `AsNoTracking()` or adding `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()` - it is case when tracking may improve query speed.

Comment: i wont gonna make crud operation with those data,i just wanna show them but maybe u are right. i will try and give u a feedback

Comment: Try also AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution

Comment: man, u just teach me awesome something!  it took like 1 second. thank u so much for your effort. i was so worried about my db design but its not even a problem for now. Thank u so much!!!!!1

Comment: What exactly helped? ;)

Comment: i add the ```AsSplitQuery``` and remove the ```AsNoTracking()``` . i tried with adding ```AsSplitQuery``` and adding ```AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()``` but theyre doing the same time. ``` AsSplitQuery``` helped me so muhc, thanks again

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv What's the use case of `AsNoTracking` if we can always use `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution` for no tracking?

Comment: @Maroun, not sure but `AsNoTracking` a little bit faster than `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution`.