# Entity Framework Core : LINQ advise needed on better approach using include for relational tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a question about Entity Framework Core and using LINQ. I would like to get the other table details while accessing the `Clients` table. I can get them using below code. There are a total of around 10 tables I need to join, in this case is the below approach is good or any other, better approach? `ClientId` is the foreign key for all tables.

Actually I am getting a warning as below

> [09:34:33 Warning] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query
> Compiling a query which loads related collections for more than one collection navigation either via 'Include' or through projection but no 'QuerySplittingBehavior' has been configured. By default Entity Framework will use 'QuerySplittingBehavior.SingleQuery' which can potentially result in slow query performance. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2134277 for more information. To identify the query that's triggering this warning call 'ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Throw(RelationalEventId.MultipleCollectionIncludeWarning))'

Code:

```
var client = await _context.Clients
                .Include(x => x.Address)
                .Include(x => x.Properties)
                .Include(x => x.ClientDetails)
                -------------------
                -------------------
                -------------------
                -------------------
                .Where(x => x.Enabled == activeOnly && x.Id == Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: The first step to optimising the query is probably to work out how you would best accomplish the same result in SQL. You can then fashion your LINQ to Entities code to best match that.

Comment: Just add `AsSplitQuery()`. Loading such data without this operator is wasting resources. Warning is totally correct. Answered similar question. about performance issues https://stackoverflow.com/a/67243921/10646316

Comment: What is "better"? We don't know the purpose of this query.

Comment: The best part about this is that if you configure it to always use one or the other, it'll still give the warning.

Comment: @CaptainPrinny really? -_-  

I wonder if you can log the query without throwing. I don't want an actual exception. I'm justcurious.

Answer (score 20):

Actually when you use Eager loading (using `include()`) It uses left join (all needed queries in one query) to fetch data. Its default the ef behavior in ef 5.
You can set `AsSplitQuery()` in your query for split all includes in separated queries. like:

```
var client = await _context.Clients
            .Include(x => x.Address)
            .Include(x => x.Properties)
            .Include(x => x.ClientDetails)
            -------------------
            -------------------
            -------------------
            -------------------
            .Where(x =>x.Id == Id).AsSplitQuery().FirstOrDefaultAsync()
```

This approach needs more database connection, but it's nothing really important.
and for the final recommendation, I advise using `AsNoTracking()` for queries to high performance.

Comment: I believe without `AsSplitQuery()` `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()` is needed otherwise it will map the same entity multiple times, I don't know if it's the same when using `AsSplitQuery()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have 3 different approaches depending on the version of EF Core you're using

EF Core 5 - as some have mentioned in previous answers there is new call which will simply break up the query into smaller subqueries and map all the relations in the end.

```
/*rest of the query here*/.AsSplitQuery();
```

If you are not able to just migrate your EF version you could still split the query manually

```
var client = await _context.Clients.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Enabled /*other conditions*/);

var Address = await _context.Addresses.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.ClientId == client.Id);

/// Because they are tracked EF's entitytracker can under the hood 
/// map the sub queries to their correct relations 
/// in this case you should not use .AsNoTracking() 
/// unless you would want to stitch relations together yourself
```

Another alternative is to write your query as a `Select` statement. This greatly improves performance but is a bit more of a hassle to construct.

```
var clientResult = await _context.Clients.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x => new 
{
 client = x, 
 x.Address,
 Properties = x.Properties.Select(property => new 
                    { 
                        property.Name /*sub query for one to many related*/ 
                    }).ToList(), 
 x.ClientDetails
}).ToListAsync();
```

it doesn't take many includes to create cartesian explosion

you can read more up on the problem at hand in this article here
[cartesian explosion in EF Core](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/cartesian-explosion-problem-in-3-1/)

and referral link to optimizing performance through EF Core can be found here
[Maximizing Entity Framework Core Query Performance](https://www.edgesidesolutions.com/maximizing-entity-framework-core-query-performance/)

Comment: Select variant makes cartesian explosion believe me. And there is no option to use AsSplitQuery with custom projection right now.

Comment: Hi Svyatoslav. 
I didn't state that select didn't result in cartesian explosion, but will under the hood perform better than .include. But yes any sort of join be it cross, left, outer left joins will give cartesian explosion if done in a bad way. But different scenarios might require different solutions

Comment: In EF any select to other table in projection is cartesian explosion, except First, FirstOrDefault, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow that comment. First or default can be used within a select statement. and select doesn't select to a table, but selects from a table.

Comment: If you use `FirstOrDefault` inside `Select` operator, EF may produce OUTER APPLY JOIN (not fast also). If you select many records in `Select` - you have cartesian explosion.

Comment: Selecting many records is not the issue, selecting many records with many relations and nested relations is the issue (it's the relations that give the cartesian explosion not the amount of records.) 
hence why the main solution by the EF team also resulted in the ```.AsSplitQuery()```

Comment: Actually `AsSplitQuery` is result of community vote.  EF team has made breaking change from EF Core 2.x - removed query splitting which was default behaviour.